# Debugging: How to 'sneak' into other class object declared in class

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-debug

I have for loop in the class(class A) that sets string data into other class(class B) that has setters and getters by calling set method of other class(class B), by creating new variable each time like this

```
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    modelClass = new ModelClass();
                    modelClass.setString(jsonObject1.getString("some"));
                    .
                    .
                    .
                          }
```

I want to see what is the current value of variables declared in modelClass(of which im setting value) and updated value after calling set method, how can i do that with debugger

Comment: setg a breakpoint on some line, and add `modelClass` to watched variables.

Comment: could you elaborate? also when I'm putting breakpoint on modelClass= new ModelClass; it saying in debugging window modelClass 'this' is not avaliable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just be clicking "step in" F5 default key in eclipse debugger. It will send you in the desired setter if you have the sources attached.

```
String tempString = jsonObject1.getString("some");
modelClass.setString(tempString);
```

Use these style: call your methods one per line and debugging will be easier. Debugging is a great part of programming. I don't know why the new technologies does not focus so much on easy debugging. For example Java 8 is very difficult for debugging - only with an appropriate code styling you can debug it.

Comment: Its stepping into JSONclass.java and showing me implementation of jsonObjectgetString not stepping into class B

Comment: okay, when my execution on modelClass = new ModelClass, its stepping into that class and all variable's value is null at that point, how can I see variable value after setting

Comment: For easiest debugging design just make your code style -one method call per line. Then the step in in the setter will be easier

Comment: Do you understand my last comment or shall I explain a bit more

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142133/discussion-between-gen-strash-and-blackhawk).

Comment: now you can step in on the line you want.. F6 till that line, then on that line hit F5 and it will work

Comment: Also after 15 breakpoints in debug window it says application is running and in frames: no frame is avaliable

Comment: modelClass.setString(tempString); place a breakpoint only on that line and press F5 when it stops

Comment: to step inside the desired class method

Comment: could you tell me how to sneak into static class, at this point noting happening debug window showing that i was connected and nothing,  singletonUsed.setModelData(modelClass); //setting object into list of singleton class

Comment: can you attack a screenshot of your current debugging progress? I cant understand your last comment. Maybe you dont have sources attacked? or you are stepping deeper?

Comment: sent you in chat